# How does "mechanical stop" and "electrical angle" differ for this potentiometer?

Tags: datasheet, potentiometer

I want to use [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/e002/0900766b80dd0e9b.pdf) potentiometer which is continuous turn. In the datasheet it says:

**Effective Electrical Angle** ...............340 ° +3 °

and there is also:

**Mechanical Angle** ................ Continuous, Stops (340 ° +8 °, -0 °) available

What are meant by these? It seems mechanical stops can vary but electrical angle is the same. Between which angles will the the potentiometer wiper be floating? Which parameter indicates that?

Answer (score 1):

The electrical angle is the range of rotation over which rotation has an effect on the position of the potentiometer.  Outside that range, the wiper will probably be floating or in contact with one of the other terminals, and incremental changes won't affect the wiper voltage.

The mechanical angle is how far it can be turned overall.  This series may be limited to 340 +8/-0 degrees by a stop, or without the stop installed it can rotate continuously.

Comment: "Outside that range, the wiper will probably be floating or in contact with one of the other terminals,".. So in the datasheet it is not clear whether the wiper will be floating when passing between the terminals?

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly, but there's an 'end voltage' specified, which implies that the wiper does stay in contact, it will run onto what is probably a metallization at the end of the resistive track that is within a certain limit of the terminal voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Effective electrical angle is the angle or better angle range in which turning the potentiometer has electrical effect. Turning the pot shaft in this range will cause a noticeable change in resistance.
On the other hand the mechanical angle is the angle range in which you can turn the pot mechanically without damage to the potentiometer.
Notice that mechanical and electrical angle overlap. Meaning that the electrical angle is inside the allowed mechanical angle. You can see total mech angle is 340+8 and electrical is 340+3. a 5 degree difference, you could turn this pot little bit further mechanically but it will not show any change in resistance (electrically).